# Performance issues when iterating numpy array

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy, vectorization

I have a 3D array of image such as

```py
[
    [
        [225, 0, 0],
        [225, 225, 0],
        ...
    ],
    [
        [225, 0, 0],
        [225, 225, 0],
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

The size of this array is 500x500x3 which is 750.000 elements.
These are simple nested loops to iterate over the array

```py
for row in arr:
    for col in row:
        for elem in col:
            elem = (2 * elem / MAX_COLOR_VAL) - 1
```

But it takes a lot of time (> 5 min) to iterate.

I'm new in numpy so may be I'm iterating arrays wrong way? How can I optimize these loops?

Comment: You should not iterate over a numpy array. In fact it is very likely that iterating over a numpy array will be slower than iterating over a Python list. The idea of a numpy array is to do operations in *bulk*. Your program will not even set the items anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays are not designed to do iteration over the elements. Likely it will even be *slower* than iterating over a Python list, since that will result in a lot of wrapping and unwrapping of elements.

Numpy arrays are designed to do processing in *bulk*. So for example calculate the elementwise-sum of two 1000×1000 matrices.

If you want to multiply all elements with `2`, divide these by `MAX_COLOR_VAL` and subtract one from these, you can simply construct a new array with:

```
arr = (2 * arr.astype(float) / MAX_COLOR_VAL) - 1
```

This will apply this operation to *all* elements.

> **Note**: note that if you iterate over a numpy array, you do *not* iterate over the indices, you iterate over the rows itself. So the `row` in `for row in arr` will return a 2d array, not the index of a 2d array.

Comment: I think casting the array to float (`arr.astype(float)`) is bit more expensive than just doing something like `2.0 * arr / MAX_COLOR_VAL) - 1`. Why is this explicit casting necessary?

Comment: @kmario23: when I run this 10'000 times with `timeit`, the `.astype(float)` gives `3.6568590000097174`, whereas the `2.0 * ...` gives `3.686493999994127`. I think it does not matter much. As a functional programmer. I do not really like this float times int idea, since it reminds too much of weakly typed languages like C#. As Python says: "explicit over implicit" :)